# Regex - grabs word from starting point to end point

Tags: regex

I have this code block unformatted in a text file and am trying to download the file in the `href`.

I have a variable called `PACK` = servicepack and the file ends in ".ispkg". So I'm trying to create a regex command to work with `grep` that will be able to find "servicepack.is_121_17_1SP2.linux64.b11206.191016 1247.ispkg".

The most I've been able to do is `\b${PACK}.*?ispkg`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> <html> <head> <title>Index of /Builds/InformationServer/11.7.1SP2/b106/linux64</title> </head> <body> <h1>Index of /Builds/InformationServer/11.7.1SP2/b106/linux64</h1> <table><tr><th><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr><tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr> <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="/Builds/InformationServer/11.7.1SP2/b106/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right"> - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td><td><a href="buildconfig.b106.191016-1247.txt">buildconfig.b106.191016-1247.txt</a></td><td align="right">16-Oct-2019 09:48 </td><td align="right">1.9K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td><td><a href="buildinfo.b106.191016-1247.txt">buildinfo.b106.191016-1247.txt</a></td><td align="right">16-Oct-2019 09:48 </td><td align="right">4.6K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[ ]"></td><td><a href="servicepack.is_11_7_1SP2.linux64.b106.191016-1247.ispkg">servicepack.is_11_7_1SP2.linux64.b106.191016-1247.ispkg</a></td><td align="right">16-Oct-2019 09:48 </td><td align="right">1.5G</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr> </table> </body></html>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use javascript ? Or only regex ?

Comment: Only regex bc this command will go inside a shell script

Comment: With a grep command ?

Comment: yea! so the full command i have going is `grep -Eoi "\b(servicepack.*?ispkg)\b" )`

Answer (score 1):

In a shell with grep, you can use this command:

```sh
grep -oP "<a href=\"\K(servicepack.*\.ispkg)(?=\">)"
```

If you want to use Javascript:

```js
let source = document.documentElement.innerHTML
let regex = /<a href="(servicepack.*\.ispkg)">/

document.documentElement.innerHTML = source.match(regex)[1]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>

<head>
<title>Index of /Builds/InformationServer/11.7.1SP2/b106/linux64</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Index of /Builds/InformationServer/11.7.1SP2/b106/linux64</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th>
        <th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th>
        <th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th>
        <th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th>
        <th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
            <hr>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td>
        <td><a href="/Builds/InformationServer/11.7.1SP2/b106/">Parent Directory</a></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right"> - </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td>
        <td><a href="buildconfig.b106.191016-1247.txt">buildconfig.b106.191016-1247.txt</a></td>
        <td align="right">16-Oct-2019 09:48 </td>
        <td align="right">1.9K</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td>
        <td><a href="buildinfo.b106.191016-1247.txt">buildinfo.b106.191016-1247.txt</a></td>
        <td align="right">16-Oct-2019 09:48 </td>
        <td align="right">4.6K</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[ ]"></td>
        <td><a href="servicepack.is_11_7_1SP2.linux64.b106.191016-1247.ispkg">servicepack.is_11_7_1SP2.linux64.b106.191016-1247.ispkg</a></td>
        <td align="right">16-Oct-2019 09:48 </td>
        <td align="right">1.5G</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
            <hr>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does the `(?=\">)` bit do?

Comment: @compuphys, is a positive lookahead (non capturing), to say that it wiil be followed by the closed `>`. Without this, the grep return `">`

Comment: Because you can't say to grep: *"I want the second capturing group"* for example ;), like in my javascript answer